# How can I know the possible starting locations in 1v1

Tags: starcraft-2

When playing 1v1 on maps with four starting locations how do I know if any of the starting locations are disabled for 1v1?

Comment: On all Blizzard maps, there are white marks that show the possible starting locations. On other tournament maps it's possible that close or far spawn locations are disabled, but when you participate a tournament you should look up such things in advance...

Comment: As Meta says even on Blizzard's ladder maps some disable close spawning locations. (http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Maps)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on specific map implementation. For example some tournaments use Metalopolis map where you can spawn only on cross locations. If you wondering about ladder maps - spawn conditions usually described in map notes. You can also check [maps description on teamliquid wiki](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Maps) where spawn location rules of different implementations are described (i.e. [metalopolis](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Metalopolis))

P.S. there is one trick about finding opponent I discovered a while ago [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Bi7b6thh8o&context=C3389386ADOEgsToPDskLRjGxzGEj5VSicdm5qI81p)

Comment: thanks. unless I am missing something the description never seems to tell it so web resources seem to be the only answer :(

Comment: Thanks for the video.  I knew that path finding knows more than what you can see but I didn't think of all those possible applications